# Java: why doesn't NumberFormatException extend ParseException?

Tags: java, exception

When parsing a string into an integer or double, a bad format will throw `NumberFormatException`, but when parsing into a `Date` (for example) a `ParseException` will be thrown.

These two have no root before `Exception`, which begs the question - why?

I want to handle all my exceptions elegantly by catching a `ParseException`

Comment: I don't necessarily think there was a conscious decision to not design it as you suggest; it may just be how it is.

Comment: Note that NumberFormat is a RuntimeException, and ParseException is not.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer - That's an important point. It's highly debatable whether NumberFormatException should have been an unchecked exception. Gosling _et al._ write in _The Java Programming Language_: "Unchecked runtime exceptions represent conditions that, generally speaking, reflect errors in your program's logic and cannot be reasonably recovered from at run time." It's hard to see how a NumberFormatException generated by parsing user input is an error in a program's logic.

Comment: Yeah: java exam says ParseException is a checked exception (when converting a string to a number) but we know that  Integer.parseInt   will throw a NumberFormatException.  I find this pretty confusing that NumberFormatException is not a checked exception.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that NumberFormatException and ParseException don't share a common ancestor for historical reasons. In any event, as of Java 7, you can write:

```
try {
    . . .
} catch (ParseException|NumberFormatException ex) {
    // elegant handling goes here
}
```

For Java 6 (or earlier), if your error handling code is sizeable, I suggest putting it in an error handling method and calling the method from the two `catch` clauses.

Answer (score 2):

A number format exception is not always a parse exception.

[`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

> "NumberFormat is the abstract base class for all number formats. This class provides the interface for formatting and parsing numbers. NumberFormat also provides methods for determining which locales have number formats, and what their names are. "

And here [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)

> "Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format. "

Comment: "...the string does not have the appropriate format" sounds like a parsing problem to me.

Comment: @TedHopp It is not a parsing problem perse.  So before something can be parsed it must be formatted.

Comment: That makes no sense. The exception is thrown when parsing text that is _already_ formatted (just formatted in a way that doesn't look like a number).

Comment: @TedHopp Actually it makes complete sense. If I am parsing a string of arbitrary length and trying to convert it to an integer I would do the following:  Read in the string (parse yes), validate it is a digit (formatting not parsing), results in a format exception.  A format problem is not a parse problem.  When I submit a paper my professor has never said "There are many parsing problems with this paper"

Comment: From Google: definition of "format": _Arrange or put into a format._ Definition of "parse": _Analyze (a sentence) into its component parts and describe their syntactic roles._ Parsing is sometimes broken down into lexical scanning and parsing (in a more narrow sense of applying grammar rules), but parsing (in the general sense) never involves formatting. Formatting is what you do to the paper when you write it. Parsing is what the prof does to the paper when he or she reads it.

Comment: I do not agree with you. A NumberFormatException is thrown when parsing. It's a complaint that the text that it has been given has the wrong format to be a number. There is no formatting involved in the call that generates the NumberFormatException. A ParseException is also a complaint about the format of the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to not duplicate code then just catch the NumberFormatException and throw a ParseException:

```
try {
    try {
        …parsing
    } catch (NumberFormatException x1) {
        throw new ParseException("",0);
    }
} catch (ParseException x2) {

    …handle all in here

}
```